# How do i get PowerQuery error messages within a VBA connection refresh error?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Excel 2016

Using WorkbookConnection.Refresh

Capturing errors

But the errors it captures dont have the same level of detail as if I were refreshing it directly from PowerQuery and seeing the error in the GUI.
All i get is "1004 Application-defined or object-defined error".
Cant see where in the object model to grab the query specific or OLEDB error from.
Has anyone been able to capture any more specific error messages.

Error is thrown from this code:-

```
Assume higher level loop iterating connections
Dim cno As WorkbookConnection
Set cno = ThisWorkbook.Connections(cn)
cno.Refresh

ErrorHandler down here capturing the error
```

Comment: What's the code that's throwing the error?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

If you have your query returned to excel table then

```
YourRangeWithinTable.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh
```

will return specific error message.

This simulates right mouse click on table and then `Refresh`.

*edit: Probably due to bug in Excel it sometimes raises specific error on second try.*

*edit2: You can get specific error also when you load table to DataModel.*